# slider cloud tag (Слайдер облако тегов)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, слайдер

Ищу похожий слайдер может кому-то попадался или знает как его сделать самому.

http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/theta-carousel-3d/full_screen_preview/12815028 .
Только мне нужен чтобы он был зациклен и не имел эффект змейки.

Comment: сильно смахивает на [этот](https://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/jQuery-Waterwheel-Carousel-Plugin.html) слайдер

Comment: Похож немного, но мне нужен именно в формате облака тегов